# Select from listbox after _Leave from another control

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a textbox with a _Leave event to verify the contents. In the situation where the user selects an item form a listbox, it does not appear to be selected until the user moves to another control. The listbox appears to have focus and the highlighted item can be changed by hovering the mouse over other entries. An item can of course be selected with a click. I would like to eliminate the need for the user to click twice to select and would prefer to change the highlighted item to selected programmatically.
Below is an example which demonstrates the problem. It cannot be seen in the code alone , but rather becomes evident when you set up a simple windows form as follows.  The window has a row of two textboxes, a listbox and a button.
The code is as follows:

```
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("1");
                listBox1.Items.Add("2");
                listBox1.Items.Add("3");
                listBox1.Items.Add("4");
                textBox1.Size = new Size(300, 22);
                textBox1.Text = "Click here first - has leave event - then select from listbox";

        }
                private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Once you close this messagebox, the clicked on item will be highlighted."+ Environment.NewLine+
                                " but not selected, and the listbox has focus." + Environment.NewLine+
                                "Click on the button or form. It then becomes selected, and written to the textbox" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                                "How can I make this happen programmatically without having to select " + Environment.NewLine +
                            "another control or click on the item again?");
}

            private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                textBox2.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: This is very clunky UI, that message box has to go.  If you want to force the user to complete steps in a specific order then consider a dialog.  Or simply not adding any items to the listbox until the textbox has valid content, use its Validating event.

Comment: Perhaps I should have made it more obvious. All this code is only an example and the messagebox is clearly only to demonstrate the problem in this forum, and never intended for the final application. In fact it would be replaced by code to validate the textbox entry in a _Leave event which is not relevant to this issue. I need to know how to initiate the _afterselect event for the listbox with a single click which has immediately beforehand initiated the textbox leave event.

Comment: To clarify, I am not actually using the validating/validate event, but rather the leave event for the textbox as per the code shown.

Comment: You are wasting your time with a fake snippet and not telling what this is really about.  And ours.

Comment: @Hans I have been chastised once before for not giving a suitable example in a question. The detail is not relevant to the question, and would overcomplicate a relatively simple problem. Including all the code would be a waste of everybodies time. The"fake snippet" was designed to make it more clear. I am sorry if you feel I have wasted your time.